# Admin links issue

Tags: navigation, uri

So if I am in my admin section

http://example.com/admin/content

and I try and click on

http://example.com/admin/structure

The url is

http://example.com/admin/admin/structure

I set the base_url but it keeps happening, is there a setting somewhere (in the table or in the admin) where I can edit it?

The base url is

`$base_url = 'http://example.com';`

Comment: I guess you've got something in .htaccess/vhost config doing the redirect, or a dodgy contrib module/configuration to do with the same. Drupal doesn't have that behaviour out of the box so you need to hunt down what's different about your site

Comment: The base url is fine, updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

And at the front of this problem is not present? If this problem only in the admin area, then you may have incorrectly configured htaccess or problem in a certain module. Because server settings I think this should not be, but it can be. Therefore, try to deploy the site on another server environments.

Comment: It has been deployed on a digital ocean droplet and locally with the same issue.

Comment: Start disabling modules one-by-one until you find the culprit @LeBlaireau, it's very unlikely anyone will be able to guess what the issue is from here

Comment: Cheers Clive, you are right it is going to be a process of elimination!

Comment: Well, to solve the problem, you can then disconnect modules. But the fact that they have a problem. htaccess tried to rule?